# Get RTSP over HTTP .NET

Tags: http, rtsp, vapix

I am in asp.net C# and I want to get an RTSP stream from axis camera tunneled over HTTP. For this I am following [axis api documentation](http://www.axis.com/files/manuals/vapix_video_streaming_43387_en_1112.pdf) (page 16 to onwards). I issued HTTP requests to camera with authorization header and `RTSP Describe` command was base 64 encoded and sent to the camera URL through POST. Here is the HTTP request.

```
POST http://195.29.168.2:20000/axis-media/media.amp HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Authorization: Basic VXNlcjpDQG1VNTNy
Host: 195.29.168.2:20000
Content-Length: 214
Content-Type: application/x-rtsp-tunnelled

[Base 64 encoded Describe command]
DESCRIBE rtsp://195.29.168.2:20000/axis-media/media.amp
     ?videocodec=h264&resolution=640x480 RTSP/1.0\r\n
    CSeq: 0\r\n
    User-Agent: Axis AMC\r\n
    Accept: application/sdp\r\n
```

I intend to get trackId parameter from `Describe` command and then use it in subsequent `Setup` command to establish the session with server but every time I send this request, 400 (bad request) parameter is sent by the camera. What am i doing wrong?
**Note:** All requests were issued from fiddler

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. Turns out you need to send each parameter to the camera on a single line.
As in:

```
DESCRIBE rtsp://195.29.168.2:20000/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264&resolution=640x480 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 0
User-Agent: Axis AMC
Accept: application/sdp
```

If you do it as shown below the camera gets a newline character in the middle and screws up the request. Kind of annoying that the api on the axis page shows it formatted like this.

```
DESCRIBE rtsp://195.29.168.2:20000/axis-media/media.amp
     ?videocodec=h264&resolution=640x480 RTSP/1.0
```

I wouldn't use fiddler, It stopped RTSP working for me completely. Wireshark works fine. I used puTty to communicate with the camera. I would ultimately like to use a web browser and use PHP to send / receive the commands but I dont get how to do it.

I know how to send a GET request if it looks like the following as it just goes in the url

```
http://myserver/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=320x240&compression=25&camera=1
```

But when it looks like the following here im confused as to how you would send it to a server from a web browser..

```
    SETUP rtsp://myserver/axis-media/media.amp/
trackID=1?videocodec=h264&resolution=640x480 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 2
User-Agent: Axis AMC
Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=20000-20001
```

It'd be great if someone can help with that, I'm just learning php could I use that?